# Show the oldest instance of a recurring task in RTM

Tags: remember-the-milk

I use Remember The Milk as a todo list and reminder. I have a monthly task that I often put off until the pile gets to high and then I do them all at once.

My task list is filled with the same task, something like:

- Pay the rent (march)
- Pay the rent (april)
- Pay the rent (may)
- Pay the rent (june)
- Pay the rent (july)

You get the idea.

I have already [created a smart list](https://www.rememberthemilk.com/help/?ctx=basics.search.advanced), but I can't find a search operator the will limit the results to a single entry, like this:

- Pay the rent (march)

What search filter can I use to show only the oldest of a set of recurring tasks?